# Complex Manifold Basic Books

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I have studied Manifold Theory form the book by Boothby. Now I want  to study Theory of Complex Manifolds. But I am a novice  in this field. Can anyone suggest me a basic book on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Follow Abel's motto: Read The Masters!
Since Kodaira and Grauert are among the undisputed masters in complex manifold theory, I recommend:
A) [Complex Manifolds and Deformation of Complex Structures](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540226147)
B) [From Holomorphic Functions to Complex Manifolds](https://books.google.fr/books/about/From_Holomorphic_Functions_to_Complex_Ma.html?id=jSeRz36zXIMC&redir_esc=y)

The Kodaira book A) is chock-full of examples. You should essentially begin by studying them, which means reading from page 28 to page 59.
 The Fritzsche-Grauert book B) is very rich but you should jump as soon as possible to Chapter IV, pages 153 to 171, which are essentially self-contained.

There are many other books on complex manifolds/varieties/several complex variables : Grauert-Remmert, Gunning-Rossi, Hörmander, Huybrechts, Krantz, Narasimhan, Shabat, Taylor, Wells,..  but none is (in my opinion) more accessible than the above two.

Comment: Conspicuously missing is one of the big names of the 20th century, Chern. As in the one who defined Chern classes. His *Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory* is a classic.